# Database "tools" for multiple platforms

Tags: c++, database, multiplatform

When I was still in high school I programmed in Delphi. When we had to work with databases (it was always .mdb if that makes a difference) we always used ADO (the object in Delphi was called "ADO Query").

Currently I am using C++ and would like to know which "tool" (I don't know what you actually call them) I can use that will compile and work properly in Windows/Linux/Mac.

I need to be able to make queries, insert records and delete records from the database.

I don't know if ADO is the best one to use, so please feel free to suggest other ones.

Thanks.

Comment: Specify target database.

Comment: It's an .odb database. If I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice_Base) from [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) should suite your needs. At least it does all you listed.